# Exported Selenium Script Throws Exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc

I recorded an action using the Selenium IDE and used the File->Export Test Cases as Python 2 (Remote Control) format.

I am using Selenium RC 2.3.0

I then ran the script from command prompt but it throws an exception.

The exported Python 2 RC code is:

```
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re

class login(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://testServer1/")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_login(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        sel.open("/WebAccess/login.html")
        sel.type("id=LoginID", "Administrator")
        sel.type("id=Password", "Administrator")
        sel.click("id=login")
        sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
        sel.click("link=Home") # This is where it fails.

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

At this line `sel.click("link=Home")` it fails with the exception

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_login (__main__.login)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\login.py", line 16, in test_log
in
    sel.click("link=Home")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\selenium.py", line 290, in click
    self.do_command("click", [locator,])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\selenium.py", line 217, in do_command
    raise Exception, data
Exception: ERROR: Element link=Home not found

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I even tried increasing the 30000 to 60000 but still no help. I can see the page is loaded fully and waiting for a while because of the higher timeout. However when executing this link=Home it fails.

The HTML code is:

```
<div class="links nopreview">
<span><a class="csiAction" href="/WebAccess/home.html#URL=centric://REFLECTION/INSTANCE/_CS_Data/null">Home</a></span>
<span>&nbsp;•&nbsp;</span>
<span><span><a class="csiAction" href="/WebAccess/home.html#URL=centric://SITEADMIN/_CS_Site">Setup</a>
</span><span>&nbsp;•&nbsp;</span>
</span><span><a title="Sign Out" class="csiAction csiActionLink">Sign Out</a></span>
</div>
```

The recorded actions using IDE are:

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/WebAccess/login.html</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=LoginID</td>
    <td>Administrator</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=Password</td>
    <td>Administrator</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=login</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=Home</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried running the test, and during running see if the "Home" link really did exist on the page?

Comment: Hi Mi Mee, Yes! I did run the test using IDE's recorded script. It works great. I was able to login and click on the Home link too. However, it fails with that exception when I wanted to run it using Python's Unittest with Selenium Server 2.3.0. I will update the recorded actions in my original post just for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an XPath such as:

```
sel.click('//a[contains(text(),"Home")]')
```

Comment: I just tried what you said and it says this exception: `======================================================================
ERROR: test_login (__main__.login)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\login.py", line 17, in test_log
in
    sel.click(link="Home")
TypeError: click() got an unexpected keyword argument 'link'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 11.266s

FAILED (errors=1)`

Comment: @Bhavani Kannan: Sorry, my mistake. I edited my post with a hopefully better suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! I tried `sel.click('//a[contains(text((),"Home")]')` and it throws the exception `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\login.py", line 17, in test_log
in
    sel.click('//a[contains(text((),"Home")]')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\selenium.py", line 290, in click
    self.do_command("click", [locator,])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\selenium.py", line 217, in do_command
    raise Exception, data
Exception: ERROR: Invalid xpath [2]: //a[contains(text((),"Home")]`

Comment: I even tried `sel.click('xpath=//a[contains(text((),"Home")]')` and it still throws the same exception as mentioned in the above comment. I wonder what could be wrong. If I comment the line that clicks on the Home link then it runs fine. Its the problem with clicking this link.

Could it be because I am using chrome in `self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome",.....` line  ?

Comment: To add, not only for Home. It does not work for Home or Setup or even Signout for that matter. It does not work for any of the links in that div. However playing back the recorded script works fine!

Comment: @Bhavani Kannan: There was a syntax error in the XPath I posted (too many parentheses after `text(()...`. Please remove one parenthesis (as shown in the edited post above) and try it again.